# Boxplot mean is incorrect in R

Tags: r

I am having a serious issue with the `boxplot` function in R.  The boxplot mislabels the median line in the graph. Even though the mean is 7.2376, on the boxplot it shows it at around 4 as shown in the image below (produced using the following code)

```
DATA <- c(0.59, 1.00, 1.00, 1.04, 1.22, 1.40, 1.72, 1.74, 1.98, 3.44, 
          3.48, 3.50, 3.53, 3.93, 4.00, 4.33, 4.72, 9.49, 10.80, 11.40,
          12.04, 16.98, 20.43, 27.27, 29.91)

> boxplot(DATA) 
> mean(DATA) = 7.2376
```

[image]

It is driving me nuts.  It only does it with this data set. The other datasets, the boxplots label the mean just fine.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Boxplots display the median (and other quantiles) not the mean.

Comment: Of course***That was a dumb mistake on my behalf. I need to get some sleep. Been up for 2 days straight. Thank you.

Comment: Goodness! Go to bed, for heaven's sake! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My comment should really be an answer...

Your confusion is not so much with the `boxplot` function, as it is with what a box plot is at all. A [box plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) typically displays only five values: min, 1st quartile, median, 3rd quartile and max. (Additionally, most plotting algorithms will split off "outliers" according to some rule.)

So the middle line in your box plot corresponds to the median, not the mean.

Comment: ... and `median(DATA)` is 3.53 in your case, so `boxplot()` is doing just what it ought to!

Comment: It is more correct, at least as far as R is concerned to refer to the *lower* and *upper* **hinge** rather than the 1st and 3rd quartiles (the 25th and 75th quantiles) as there are multiple definitions of quantiles etc.

Comment: +1 to Simpson: `hinge` != `quartile`. I suppose there might be an occasional ambiguity from the definition of quartile, but I rather doubt it could happen very often. The hinges are most extreme actual values within the quartile values so whether you interpolate in various ways should not affect the hinge.

Answer (score 7):

**I have to redeem myself for this dumb mistake. For those looking to label the mean you can do the following:**

```
> DATA_mean <- data.frame(Group ="A", Measure = DATA) #Make a data.frame first
> attach(DATA_mean)                                   #Attach the data
> boxplot( Measure ~ Group)                           #Draw your boxplot as above
> means <- by(Measure, Group, mean)                   #Calculate mean and assign
> points(1, means, pch = 21, cex =1.5, bg = "blue")   #Label mean on boxplot


#The default center is 1 for the boxplots, if you have more than one, it would be 1:2:3...etc
```

[image: Boxplot with mean labeled]

Hope this helps someone out. That was a embarassing mistake on my behalf. Time to sleep.

Thank you all for correcting me right away.